# Why is eslint complaining about Record in my typescript file?

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm a javascripter since many years that's now being subjected to an extremely bad eslint config.

There are several things throwing me - for one, I can't use types from declaration files (i.e. a type defined in `.d.ts`) so I've had to move all types to regular `.ts` files and just export/import them.

But the most frustrating one - `Record` is not recognized.

[image: screenshot showing Record being complained about]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I read in another thread that I should just add `'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'` in `extends`, but to no avail... Here's our `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
    "root": true,
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "airbnb-typescript/base",
        "plugin:@ota-meshi/svelte/recommended",
        "plugin:import/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "ignorePatterns": [
        ".eslintrc.cjs",
        "**/*.d.ts",
        "**/*.html",
        "vite.config.js",
        "svelte.config.js",
        "libraries/",
        "node_modules/"
    ],
    "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "prettier"],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.svelte"],
            "parser": "svelte-eslint-parser",
            "parserOptions": {
                "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
            },
            "rules": {
                "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
                "import/no-mutable-exports": "off",
                "no-underscore-dangle": "off"
            }
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "import/internal-regex": "^$",
        "import/resolver": {
            "typescript": {
                "alwaysTryTypes": true,
                "project": "./tsconfig.json"
            },
            "vite": {
                "configPath": "./vite.config.js"
            },
            "node": {}
        }
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "project": ["./tsconfig.json"],
        "tsconfigRootDir": "./",
        "extraFileExtensions": [".svelte"]
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", "tab"],
        "@typescript-eslint/indent": ["error", "tab"],
        "prettier/prettier": 2,
        "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
            "error",
            {
                "devDependencies": true
            }
        ],
        "import/extensions": "off",
        "import/no-unresolved": "error",
        "import/order": [
            "error",
            {
                "pathGroups": [
                    {
                        "pattern": "$/**",
                        "group": "external",
                        "position": "after"
                    }
                ],
                "groups": [
                    "builtin",
                    "external",
                    "internal",
                    "unknown",
                    "parent",
                    "sibling",
                    "index",
                    "object",
                    "type"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @caTS any chance you can elaborate on what's bad about the config? I have two typescript devs that are arguing about it and one config seems more complicated than the other.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I created a new project, I installed the following packages: @ota-meshi/eslint-plugin-svelte, @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin, @typescript-eslint/parser, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb-typescript, eslint-plugin-prettier, typescript. Afterwards I created a single file called index.ts with one line of code in it `const prices: Record<string, number> = {};`. I also took the configuration from the question and with all of that, I ran `npx eslint --config ./.eslintrc.json index.ts`  but I only get a @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars warning about `prices`.

Comment: Ah interesting, so it's not throwing in `.ts` files but throwing in `.svelte` files.